# Terminal doesn't require sudo for things it should

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I have a new Lenovo system with Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed. So far, I have only created the administrator account. In setting up the machine, I've had to do a few operations with the Terminal. It does not require me to use sudo. It just accepts the bare command. I've never seen this happen in any previous distro, and it makes me nervous--am I operating as root without meaning to?

My command prompt in Terminal is a dollar sign ($), NOT an octothorpe (#).

Comment: Please give us an example. One *should* be able to do: `ip addr show` without sudo but one should *not* be able to do `apt update` without sudo. What command(s) is/are troublesome? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, this is reassuring! 'apt update' does indeed require sudo. I must just not have used a restricted command previously. (Distros I've used in the past required sudo for _every_ command, regardless.) How do I mark this solved?

Comment: I will convert my comment into an asnwer that you may accept. Heaven knows, I really crave the points.

Comment: You can delete your question, which is the best in this case as this will not help other users.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, and a great many other Linux distributions, users alone, without the use of sudo may make routine inquiries, for example:

```
ip addr show
```

These inquiries only tell us some non-priveledged details but they do not allow us to change anything.

On the other hand, if we wish to change something system-wide, for instance, install new software:

```
sudo apt install abcde
```

Then sudo is required. Also, in many cases, to even read some system files, sudo is required.

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myrouter.nmconnection 
cat: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myrouter.nmconnection: Permission denied
```

Of course, we may change anything in our /home/user directories without sudo:

```
rm /home/user/Photos/mycat.jpg
```

The behavior you've descibed, that some but not all commands require sudo, is normal in Ubuntu.